# Managing LGPO via PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

Scope: change update settings in local group policy.

Fact: GroupPolicy CMDLets don't allow you to manage group policy if there's no DC.

Does anyone have any idea about how to edit/manage Local Group Policy via CLI in windows > 2k8 seen powershell GPO cmdlets can't work without a domain forest? 
I'd rather avoid 'GroupPolicy' folder porting and direct access to windows register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want centralized management you need a domain. Microsoft doesn't provide an official (much less straightforward) way to handle local policies on the commandline. I'd say your best bet is identifying which registry values reflect the policy settings you want to deploy and then write the settings directly to the registry with a script.

Comment: I'd love to! But those are 'server to sell' and i can't add it to a domain of mine! Anyway, I somehow agree with microsoft: there's no sense in remote managing a LGPO if you can 'deploy' machine templates/make your own "ISO".
TY anyway

Comment: Really, it seems there's no way to make this except gpedit.msc or direct/cli reg edits....

Answer (score 0):

I have written a function that does this, however LGPO.exe must be on the device or a valid path. [LGPOPSmodule](https://github.com/PowerShellCrack/LGPOPSmodule)

Its modified from my original one for configurations here: [OS-Configs](https://github.com/PowerShellCrack/OS-Configs)